# Confused by template argument deduction

Tags: c++, templates, c++03, template-argument-deduction

I've created the following struct:

```
template<class T>
struct not_equals
{
  not_equals(T d):data(d){};
  bool operator()(T const & in)
  {
    return data != in;
  }
  T data;
};
```

My expectation was that since I need to pass some value of concrete type `d`  to the constructor, template argument `T` will be deduced from type of `d`.

However, this does not happens.

```
not_equals('0'); // fails with 'missing template arguments'
char zero = '0';
not_equals(zero); // same as above
not_equals<char>('0'); // compiles without errors
```

What is the reason for compiler not recognizing type of template argument?

Comment: C++17 would allow to deduce type from constructor.

Comment: It [will work in C++17](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_deduction), but not just yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

c++17 will allow [class template deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_deduction)

Until then, you can create a "make" function:

```
template <class T> auto make_not_equals(const T& d) -> not_equals<T>
{
  return {d};
}
```

```
auto z = make_not_equals('0');
```

---

This is the C++03 version of the make function:

```
template <class T> not_equals<T> make_not_equals(const T& d)
{
    return not_equals<T>(d);
}
```

Unfortunately when you declare a variable you need to spell the whole type with the template because of missing `auto` feature, but the make function can still be helpful in a deduced context, for instance for a parameter:

```
template <class T> void foo(not_equals<T> ne);
```

```
void test()
{
   foo(make_not_equals('0'));
}
```

Comment: Just a remark, this is C++11, I don't think there is a way in C++03 as required by OP

Comment: @IlBeldus: That can be rewritten for C++03, just move `not_equals<T>` in place of `auto`.